# Error installing mod_wsgi: Microsoft VS++ 14.0 required

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install mod_wsgi using:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

and prompt an error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I already set my Apache home folder to the apache folder installed via Wamp Server 64. I already have the x86 and x64 of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable version 14.22.27281.0, Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 and updated setuptools using `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

I ran the `pip install mod_wsgi` both on Windows CMD and Developer Command Prompt for VS2019

Full error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\darrius\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Darrius\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qivvz49q\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Darrius\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qivvz49q\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Darrius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kgy8oddz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\darrius\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mod-wsgi'
     cwd: C:\Users\Darrius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qivvz49q\mod-wsgi\
Complete output (26 lines):
c:\users\darrius\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
running build_ext
building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\darrius\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Darrius\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qivvz49q\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Darrius\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qivvz49q\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Darrius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kgy8oddz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\darrius\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't "see" your *VStudio* installation. As a workaround, check: https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/Mod_WSGI.